# Joining csv in order

Tags: join, csv, merge

I'm attempting to joint about 30 csv files that need to be in the correct order.

I have been looking at using the copy *.csv new.csv DOS command. Does this join the csv files in the order that they are listed in the directory? Because it would take me a lot of time to use the alternative is:
copy file1 + file2 + file3 newfile
But it would take ages to write all the file names down. Anyone can clarify this?

Answer (score 2):

Using copy *.csv new.csv will join the csv files using filename as sort order (ascending).
If you want to join the csv file using different sort order, you can use copy file1 + file2 + file3 newfile.